# uploading files inside a folder that doesn't exist yet in php

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to upload files using a form and placing them into folders that are corresponding to the user name logged in. How can i make it so that it uploads the file into a folder that hasn't been created yet. The folder should be according to the username which is $user in this case.

Below is my code:

dbptft.php

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($user); ?>!</p>
      <?php      
      $directorypath = "/uploads/". $user;
       mkdir($directorypath, 0644);

$target_path = "$directorypath/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

this is my form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="dbptft.php">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile">
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

errors:

```
    Welcome S00024972!


Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/aukwizcq/public_html/ptft/dbptft.php on line 19

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploads/S00024972/Capture.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/aukwizcq/public_html/ptft/dbptft.php on line 25

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpubGytY' to '/uploads/S00024972/Capture.PNG' in /home/aukwizcq/public_html/ptft/dbptft.php on line 25
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!Error : (0)
```

Comment: Does dbptft.php have premissions to upload files?

Comment: @Zerquix18 whenever i change its permissions it gives me errors. shouldn't it be the folder that permissions should be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls are to `/uploads` not to `/home/aukwizcq/public_html/ptft/uploads`.  Remove the prefixing `/` otherwise you are referring to the server's root directory `/` as an absolute path instead of a relative path to the uploads directory.

I'd also add `if (!is_dir($directorypath))` before the `mkdir()`, unless the directory is always unique, to avoid a directory already exists notice.

Comment: devon one question, if i wanna make it then in the future so that when the same username uploads another file, it wouldn't give an error saying already exists? it would just upload it to his folder.

Comment: @KyleJosh, that's exactly what my second paragraph is for.

Comment: oh sorry, your awesome!